# Add Upload button for OpenAPI 2.0 file as Octet-Stream

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

**Context**

- I am using OpenAPI ver 2.0
- I have API which consumes `application/octet-stream` (Java `InputStream`)

**Issue**

In OpenAPI ver 2.0 I can only set input type as `multipart/form-data` ([link](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/)). When I have applied this solution for my API I am getting following error: `Unsupported Media Type` which is normal.

**Question**

Is it possible to have upload button using OpenAPI ver 2.0 and `application/octet-stream` like:

[image]